# Open modal on page load without button

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal that opens by clicking a button.
How can I make it open on page load so I can discard the button all together?
I need to change the below function, but not sure how.

```
var modal = document.getElementById("promoModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("promo-close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and the html

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="promoModal" class="promomodal">    
  <div class="promo-modal-content">
    <span class="promo-close">&times;</span>
   CONTENT GOES HERE
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.promomodal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause it to be hidden in the first place. Where's the CSS?

Comment: so set the CSS to block?

Comment: Usually, in order to hide something, we just add a CSS class of something like "hidden" to the element, where the `.hidden` class is just `display:none;`. So, to show something, you just remove the `hidden` CSS class. In your case, if you want to see the modal right away, simply don't hide it to begin with.

Comment: yes @epascarello - set the css to block

Comment: You only need to set a block element to `display:block` if you had previously set the `display` to something else. In your case, don't do that initial setting of the `display` and the element will just show as normal.

Comment: it is set to display:none - the button triggers the display: block. Basically, I need it to open with block, but keep the display:none relevant for the modal closing.

Comment: Just remove the `display:none` that is initially set on the item. You can set that later when you need it hidden.

Comment: You are making it more complicated than it needs to be. Just set the CSS to block to start and it will be there....

Comment: @epascarello It's the initial `display:none` that's causing the issue. Just removing that solves the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `display:none` from the initial styling of the element:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("promoModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("promo-close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.promomodal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="promoModal" class="promomodal">    
  <div class="promo-modal-content">
    <span class="promo-close">&times;</span>
   CONTENT GOES HERE
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also

```
<div class="promomodal-demo">
    <div id="list-builder"></div>
    <div id="promoModal" class="promomodal">    
      <div class="promo-modal-content">
        <span class="promo-close">&times;</span>
       CONTENT GOES HERE
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
#list-builder {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}
#promoModal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #79C4F8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99;
}
.promo-close{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

js:

```
var delay = 100; // milliseconds
        var cookie_expire = 0; // days
        var cookie = localStorage.getItem("list-builder");

        if(cookie == undefined || cookie == null) {
          cookie = 0;
        }
        if(((new Date()).getTime() - cookie) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) > cookie_expire) {
            $("#list-builder").delay(delay).fadeIn("slow", () => {
                $("#promoModal").fadeIn("slow", () => {});
            });
            $(".promo-close").click(() => {
                $("#list-builder, #promoModal").hide();
                localStorage.setItem("list-builder", (new Date()).getTime());
            });
        }
```

**Note:**need to call jquery file.

thank you

Comment: You're kidding, right? Starting with an "answer" that contains no explanation for what it does or how it solves the problem and ending with JQuery and `localStorage` to solve a problem that can be solved by removing one line of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reason to have it set to display: none to start with (I can't think of any reason why you would), just add a:

```
  window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("promoModal").style.display = "block";
 }
```

On the other hand, having a web page open with a modal is a pretty good way of annoying people to the point of exiting your site quick smart.